# Substitute and drop characters in column names

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have the following names of variables:

```
vars <- c("var-1.caps(12, For]","var2(5,For]","var-3.tree.(15, For]","var-3.tree.(30, For]")
```

I need to clean these names in order to get the following result:

```
clean_vars <- c("var1.caps_12_For","var2_5_For","var3.tree_15_For","var3.tree_30_For")
```

So, basically I would like to drop `-`, `(` and `]`.

I was using this approach:

```
gsub("\\(.*\\]","",vars)
```

But it drops everything between `(` and `]`. It neither drops the symbol `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can capture as a group.  Match the pattern for a `.` if it exists followed by a `(` (metacharacters - so escape `\\`), followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) captured as a group (`(...)`), followed by a `,` and zero or more spaces (`\\s*`), then capture the word (`[A-Za-z]+`) as second capture group.  In the replacement, specify the backreference (`\\1`, `\\2`) of the capture group along with `_` to get the expected output

```
out <-  sub("\\.?\\((\\d+),\\s*([A-Za-z]+)\\]$", "_\\1_\\2", vars)
out
#[1] "var-1.caps_12_For" "var2_5_For"        "var-3.tree_15_For" "var-3.tree_30_For"

sub('-', '', out)
#[1] "var1.caps_12_For" "var2_5_For"       "var3.tree_15_For" "var3.tree_30_For"
```

Comment: @Fluxy I checked your `clean_vars` and it is matching the output showed

Comment: Sorry, I see `var-1.caps_12_For` instead of `var1.caps_12_For`. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @Fluxy sorry, I missed that part.  Updated

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in case of multiple occurances it would be better to use `gsub`?

Comment: @Fluxy If it is just to remove the multiple occurences. you can use `gsub`, but here, you want to insert some characters as well.  So, I captured as group to make sure that we don't miss

Comment: @Fluxy If you don't want to iinsert the `_`, `gsub("\\]|-|\\.?\\(|(?<=,)\\s*", "", vars, perl = TRUE)`. should. work